# cannot override function _prepare_sale_order_line_data python odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

i try to update value return from function _prepare_sale_order_line_data in purchase_order.py enterprise modul odoo,

i will add value analytic account sale_order_line from purchase_order_line

this is my code

```
@api.model
def _prepare_sale_order_line_data(self, line, company, sale_id):
    print 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzxxxxxxxxxxx'
    res = super(purchase_order, self)._prepare_sale_order_line_data(line, company, sale_id)
    print 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    for po_line in self.order_line:
        res.update({'my_analytic_account_id': po_line.analytic_account_id.id})
    return res
```

why this code cannot work (did not make any changes)? what should i do?

Thank you

Comment: could you please add trace in your question, so that it will be easy to help you out

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors here. The most prominant is that you are trying to call the function inside where the function is defined. In the following line:

```
res = super(purchase_order, self)._prepare_sale_order_line_data(line, company, sale_id)
```

You are calling the function incorrectly, with less perameters than in the definition and it is inside the definition itself. Any one of these things would cause an error.

Comment: I get the solution
calling the function is correctly, this is my error analytic_account_id which should account_analytic_id, and depends inter_company_rules module in manifest.